# run WPS from inside a cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to learn to  develop in cocoa and objective C.
I would like to run a run WPS from inside a cocoa application.
This command works from a terminal: wps test.sas
The command creates a test.log and a test.lst.

1. How do I execute this command
   from the C program
2. Is there a way
   to read the test.lst file into a
   text window in application builder?

It would be fantatic if you could help me :-)

Regards,
T

Answer (score 4):

(1) To run the command, use [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

(2) To read the file, use [NSString's + stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:) method

(3) To put the contents of the file into an NSTextView in your user interface, use [NSTextView's setString:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSText/setString:) method.

If little to none of the above makes sense, you need to [start here](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Cocoa/index.html).